# How to draw a picture of a Periodic function?

Tags: plotting

The period of function f [x] is 2, and the analytical formula for interval [-1,1] is f [x]=x ^ 2

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_?NumericQ] = Piecewise[{{x^2, -1 <= x <= 1}, {f[x + 2] == f[x]}}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the original interval start from `-1`, we using `Mod[x, 2,-1]`.

```
Clear[f];
f[x_] := x^2 /; -1 <= x <= 1;
Plot[f[Mod[x, 2,-1]], {x, -3, 5}]
```

Or

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_] := x^2 /; -1 <= x <= 1;
f[x_] := f[x - 2] /; x >= 1;
f[x_] := f[x + 2] /; x <= -1
Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{{x^2, -1 <= x <= 1}}, f[x - 2 Sign[x]]]

Plot[f[x], {x, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using [`SawtoothWave`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SawtoothWave.html)

```
Plot[(2 SawtoothWave[(x + 1)/2 - 1] - 1)^2, {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

You can also use rescaling and translation Mod[x,1]

```
Plot[(2 Mod[(x+1)/2,1]-1)^2,{x,-10,10}]
```